# Problem with a bootstrap list group column

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My list group doesn't work as expected when text is too long. I want the first column to be high as the second one when this change its size. How can I do this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="list-group">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Nome e cognome:</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6"><b>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some </b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Luogo e data di nascita:</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6"><b>(dati)</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Residenza:</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6"><b>(dati)</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Cellulare:</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6"><b>(dati)</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6">Email:</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-6"><b>(dati)</b></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

This is the screen of my issue:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and fix the snippet so it demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I removed the asp.net labels and linked the correct bootstrap version